# Calculating sum of sequence number when the sequence restarts after reaching maximum in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table say dt

```
    dt <- data.table(reg = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02"), 
                     seq = c(735052, 835182, 935447, 5642, 135795, 327855, 328497, 339842, 339979, 340176))
> dt
       reg    seq
1:      01 735052
2:      01 835182
3:      01 935447
4:      01 5642
5:      01 135795
6       02 327855
7:      02 328497
8:      02 339842
9:      02 339979
10:      02 340176
```

I want to compute the total available seq for each class. For example for class "02" total available sequence is (340176 - 327855 +1 = 12322).

In case of class "01" the sequence have restarted after reaching the maximum(1000000). so in this case total available sequence must be (1000000 - 735052 + 135795 = 400743 ), how can I do this.

I need to generate a monotonous sequence and need to get the total sum of that sequence which is equal to (last seq - first seq + 1) . Also in the case when the sequence is restarting after reaching the threshold value in that case (example reg = 01) then sum of seq is (threshold - first seq code + last seg code)

Comment: Your condition is not clear

Comment: I need to generate a monotonous sequence and need to get the total sum of that sequence which is equal to (last seq - first seq + 1) . Also in the case when the sequence is restarting after reaching the threshold value in that case (example reg = 01) then sum of seq is (threshold - first seq code + last seg code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different ways but one option is below:

```
dt[,.(ifelse(diff(.SD[c(1,.N)]$seq)<0,1000000-diff(.SD[c(.N,1)]$seq),diff(.SD[c(1,.N)]$seq))),by=.(reg)]
#    reg   V1
# 1:  01 400743
# 2:  02  12321
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit longer but a more straightforward way (to me) than above:

```
dt[, num_reset := cumsum(shift(seq, fill = FALSE) > seq), by = reg]
dt[, new_seq :=  num_reset * 999999 + seq]
dt[, max(new_seq) - min(new_seq) + 1, by = reg]
```

The steps are 1. Count the number of resets, 2. create `new_seq` and 3. calculate the difference between max and min.